# Complete List of English Compound Words?

Tags: resource-request, frequency, compounds

I am looking for a complete list of English compound words (or a frequency list of English compound words).

Ideally, I'd prefer a list that lists the compound word and also its constituent words (for instance, widespread,wide,spread).

So far, I've found [Wiktionary's category listing for compound words](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_compound_words), but it has the drawbacks of being a Wiki rather than a professional publication and also of not listing the component words.

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_compound_words

Comment: I doubt that the number of English compounds is finite, and if not, you can't make a finite list of them.

Comment: Even if that were true, and I'm not interested in arguing that point, you could certainly make a *frequency list* of compound words in English, which was also in my original question.

Comment: As far as completeness (or recall) is concerned, probably nothing else beats the English wiktionary.